# Error -2147417851 Method '~' of object '~' failed in VB6 with word 2003

Tags: vb6

We have very strange error here for which we could not find any solution. I hope VB6 ,word expert could help us in this.

We have our code in VB6. There is a functionality in the code in which we send the word documents to client/users through the code. Word documnets have bookmarks in them. During send operation code creates word object, generates the bookmarks in the ActiveDocument and send it to client.

However, users are getting below error while sending the documents. We have tried tried users scenarios in our local machines the error does not get reproduced. Below is the error description through the log for the user.

Error Description -2147417851 Method '~' of object '~' failed

```
Source     RevisionDLL     CGCDocWordApp:ActiveBookmarkSet Method
RevisionDLL     CGCDocWordApp:GetNextTypeBookmark Method
RevisionDLL     IDocument:GenerateDocument Method
DistribDll     IDistribution::PrepareDoc
```

Note: The error occuring when the documents are in bunch. and the error is inconsistent.
We checked the MDAC version of all servers. MDAC version are matching

Which googled around for all possible solutions but neither solution is working for us. Some of the links are as below.

http://www.justskins.com/forums/subject-method-of-object-10350.html 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?395362-Method-of-object-Failed

Comment: When you say (we send the word documents to client/users through the code.)  Is that a word doc being copied? if so make sure the PC that is  sending has the proper permissions against the drive it's being sent or possibly copied to..

Comment: "Method '~' of object '~' failed" means that an SEH exception is caught usually by the `DispInvoke` API function. Try automating Word with late-bound calls (dimension your vars As Object instead of As Word.Application etc.)

Comment: Hi Suzy basically we are sending documents through the application the code is written on 'Send' button click and the users have all permissions to send the docs.

Comment: Hi All,

Thank you for you reply I will impliment the solutions provided by you all.

And let you all know about the status.

Thank you so much.:)

Comment: Hi Suzy,We use late binding to automate the word application.

Comment: Does any body know what could be the issue causing this inconsistent error.

Comment: Please note that my application is windows based application running on Citrix server.